# Factorial of a number in python

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

```
def fact(n):
    if n<0:
        return 0
    if (n==0 or n==1):
        return 1
    else:
        n * fact(n-1)

n = int(input("Enter a number"))
fact(n)
```

i dont know why its giving me a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Answer (score 0):

You failed to return a value from your recursion case:

```
    else:
        n * fact(n-1)
```

You need

```
    else:
        return n * fact(n-1)
```

The default return value is `None`, so you end up trying to multiply `None` by `n` at every level above the second from the bottom.

For instance, when you try fact(3), you recur ...

```
3 * fact(2)
  2 * fact(1)
    fact(1) is 1 ... return that ...
  2 * 1 is 2 ... but you then return None ...
3 * None ... is illegal
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant

```
return n * fact(n-1)
```

Comment: Why answer _and_ mark as duplicate?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi My closure was for the "simple typo" reason. A gold Python member came along and had a different idea, which automatically overrides me.

Comment: Ah, I see. Questions as basic as this almost always have duplicates though -- better to find one and link it instead of answering.